# Methods aren't having an effect on a SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: java, android, swiperefreshlayout

Every method I use on the SwipeRefreshLayout doesn't have an effect on it. I have quite new to Java, so it might have been how I have been defining my variables.

Here is my onCreate():

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("application_settings", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Boolean darkTheme = (pref.getBoolean("DarkTheme", false));
        if(darkTheme == false){
           setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        }
        else{
           setTheme(R.style.DarkAppTheme);
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        .
        .
        .
       final SwipeRefreshLayout test = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);
        if (darkTheme == true) {
            test.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.grey_check);
        }
        else{
            test.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorPrimary);
        }
        test.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {

            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                test.setRefreshing(true);
                OnSwipe();
            }
        });
   }
```

and here is my OnSwipe() method:

```
public void OnSwipe(){
      mRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);
      .
      . // Some data processing
      .       
      mRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
```

Whenever I use a method to affect its state, nothing happens except for the icon to show up. It will not stop showing the refresh icon.

Answer (score 1):

edit: I read your question quickly 5 mins ago, I edit the answer:

You should set this as global variable:

```
SwipeRefreshLayout test;
```

then in onCreate(), set it like this:

```
test = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);
```

after these 2 steps, you can use it like this:

```
test.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            test.setRefreshing(true);
            OnSwipe();
        }
    });
```

and onSwipe():

```
public void OnSwipe(){
  .
  . // Some data processing
  .       
  test.setRefreshing(false);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution isn't working, it still isn't calling OnSwipe(). +1 though for trying to help me.

Comment: be sure you place <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout> view correctly at your activity layout XML. It must be work, you are missing another point I think. Also you can move "test.setRefreshing(true);" at the first line of the onSwipe() method, but I don't think this issue is related about this line.